# movement of phone causes unexpected result in code

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which makes no reference to the sensor aspect of the phone.  At a certain pint the program sends an sms and then sleeps for five minutes.   If I move the phone during this sleep period a dialog box displayed earlier reappears.   I realise this is rather vague without code at this stage but to start with is this something to be expected.   I am wondering if one of the broadcast listeners is being triggered by the movement but even if this is so I cant make the connection with the dialog box.   Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you handling layout changes (landscape<>portrait)? That's a movement trigger that will have effect on your code? It'll restart the activity if you've not added the right stuff in the manifest for one.

Comment: Thanks Nanne - that led me to the solution

Comment: You need to appropriately update your application logic in code and or  manifest.xml file to take care of (if needed disable) orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Fist off, I would take care of the orientation change possibility by forcing the app into an orientation by using the   option in the manifest file.

Second, I would look at what other apps are on the device that might have an affect on this functionality. Assuming by your question, your app uses BroadcastReceivers. If this is the case, provided your business logic permits, use explicit intents ( new Intent(this, )) in place of implicit intents and receivers. If this is not possible because of business logic, then perhaps using permissions to protect against accidental implicit intent receive triggers. Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html (its a good starting place anyways).

Without more info on your specific business logic or source code I can't go much deeper into the problem, but my first suggestion would probably give the simplest result. Just remember to set this attribute for each activity that this problem affects.

Steve.